# iPhone - get data from YAJLiOS parser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, yajl

I have some code where i using yajl parser:

```
NSArray *JSONArray = [tempContainer yajl_JSON];
NSLog(@"array of json is = %@",JSONArray);
```

and after parsing i got some json data like

```
{ 
  "account_number": "123", 
  "some_stuff": "231",
}
```

---

**My question is next: how i get data from specific value of parsed data.**

*ex. i want "account_number" , and i get "123"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into the streaming API to build NSMutableDictionaries from JSON:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"example.json"];

 YAJLParser *parser = [[YAJLParser alloc] initWithParserOptions:YAJLParserOptionsAllowComments];
 parser.delegate = self;
 [parser parse:data];
 if (parser.parserError)
   NSLog(@"Error:\n%@", parser.parserError);

 parser.delegate = nil;
 [parser release];

 // Include delegate methods from YAJLParserDelegate 
 - (void)parserDidStartDictionary:(YAJLParser *)parser { }
 - (void)parserDidEndDictionary:(YAJLParser *)parser { }

 - (void)parserDidStartArray:(YAJLParser *)parser { }
 - (void)parserDidEndArray:(YAJLParser *)parser { }

 - (void)parser:(YAJLParser *)parser didMapKey:(NSString *)key { }
 - (void)parser:(YAJLParser *)parser didAdd:(id)value { }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Your question should be clear and without typo**

Are you sure you are getting json data in the same format as you typed in your question or it just a typo?

I assume your json data is like 
{
"account_number": "123",
"some_stuff": 231,
}

then its just a simple dictionary and you can get the value using valueForKey method.